# Import to Python a specific format file line per line

Tags: python-3.x

How can I Import this file which contains plain text with numbers?

It's difficult to import because the first line contains 7 numbers and the second line contains 8 numbers...

In general:

LINE 1: 7 numbers.
LINE 2: 8 numbers.
LINE 3: 7 numbers.
LINE 4: 8 numbers.
... and so on

I just had tried to read but cannot import it. I need to save the data in a NumPy array.

```
filepath = 'CHALLENGE.001'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
       line = fp.readline()    
       cnt += 1
```

[LINK TO DATA](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uft4m0rldsafc5t/CHALLENGE.001?dl=0)

This file contains information for each frequency has is explained below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to skip the blank lines when reading as well.

Just check if the first line is blank. If it isn't, read 3 more lines. 
Rinse and repeat.

Here's an example of both a numpy array and a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filepath = 'CHALLENGE.001'

data = []

headers = ['frequency in Hz',
        'ExHy coherency',
        'ExHy scalar apparent resistivity',
        'ExHy scalar phase',
        'EyHz coherency',
        'EyHx scalar apparent resistivity',
        'EyHx scalar phase',
        're Zxx/√(µo)',
        'im Zxx/√(µo)',
        're Zxy/√(µo)',
        'im Zxy/√(µo)',
        're Zyx/√(µo)',
        'im Zyx/√(µo)',
        're Zyy/√(µo)',
        'im Zyy/√(µo)',
        ]

with open(filepath) as fp:
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not len(line):
            break

        fp.readline()
        line2 = fp.readline()
        fp.readline()

        combined = line.strip().split() + line2.strip().split()

        data.append(combined)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers).astype('float')
array = np.array(data).astype(np.float)

# example of type
print(type(df['frequency in Hz'][0]))
```

Comment: The only additional thing is... the data is dtype=object, but in order to plot (frequency vs ExHy coherency) I just do the next: 
`x = df.frequency.values.astype(float)`. But how can I convert every value in dataframe to float?

Comment: @PAULGOYES Just add `.astype('float')`  when creating your dataframe. I changed my example to reflect that.